# mongoose populate multiple times with the same path

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to populate a model multiple times with the same path "recipes" at path: "suppliesData.supplies", "recipes" at path: "altRecipes.altRecipe" and at path: "employee"

```
  Table.updateTable(id, order, {}, (err, order) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  Order.populate(
    order,
    {
      path: "recipes",
      populate: {
        path: "suppliesData.supplies",
      }
    },
    (err, order) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
       Order.populate(
    order,
    {
      path: "employee",
      }
    },
    (err, order) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
     Order.populate(
    order,
    {
      path: "recipes",
      populate: {
        path: "altRecipes.altRecipe"
      }
    },
    (err, order) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      res.json(order);
    }
  );
});
    }
  );
});
    }
  );
});
```

}

in the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) it explicitly says:

If you call populate() multiple times with the same path, only the last one will take effect.

// The 2nd `populate()` call below overwrites the first because they
// both populate 'fans'.

```
Story.
  find().
  populate({ path: 'fans', select: 'name' }).
  populate({ path: 'fans', select: 'email' });
// The above is equivalent to:
Story.find().populate({ path: 'fans', select: 'email' });
```

in my case both paths "suppliesData.supplies" and "altRecipes.altRecipe" populates recipes and so, I can understand what is happening but then, they do not explain how to solve that case and I can't find any example on how to do it.

any help very appreciated.

the Json is:

```
 {
    "orders": [
        "pizza x(1) "
    ],
    "recipes": [
        {
            "state": true,
            "_id": "5b50f78924d76e204c0a2d83",
            "name": "Baby Biff",
            "suppliesData": [
                {
                    "_id": "5b50f78924d76e204c0a2d88",
                    "qt": "1",
                    "un": "kg",
                    "supplies": "5b32c4096a257d45950d7b12"
                }],
            "altRecipes": [
                {
                    "_id": "5b50f78924d76e204c0a2d89",
                    "qt": "25",
                    "un": "gr",
                    "altRecipe": {
                        "adc": true,
                        "state": true,
                        "_id": "5b4fc8ddbf9d613b47705554",
                        "costCenter": "5b43e061cb1b773ce3cd1a0d",
                        "adic": {
                            "_id": "5b4fc8ddbf9d613b47705555",
                            "qr": "350",
                            "un": "kg"
                        },
                        "add": {
                            "_id": "5b4fc8ddbf9d613b47705556",
                            "qt": "100",
                            "un": "gr"
                        },
                        "name": "french fries",
                        "suppliesData": [
                            {
                                "_id": "5b4fc8ddbf9d613b47705558",
                                "qr": "1",
                                "un": "kg",
                                "supplies": "5b3f9f13be9d461735f63f4a"
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "5b4fc8ddbf9d613b47705557",
                                "qt": "1",
                                "un": "gr",
                                "supplies": "5b32b86b97473f36a3d62297"
                            }
                        ],
                        "min": "3",
                        "max": "5",
                        "opt": "4",
                        "crit": "2",
                        "exp": "3",
                        "price": "8",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5b5bb5d536131a4d1d6d2f6c",
    "employee": "59c46d202e2164b5c1aa1b93",
    "sent": true,
    "table": "5b3305ca337b8e2846e33e67",
    "date": "2018-07-28T00:16:21.698Z",
    "orderNumber": 210,
    "__v": 0
```

edit: sorry was looking at the wrong Json, this is the one

update: I did the change as it shows and now it populates employee and path: "altRecipes.altRecipe" but not the path: "suppliesData.supplies"(or yes it does populates  "suppliesData.supplies" but it gets overwritten by "altRecipes.altRecipe"  ), so it is working as the documentation says.. the problem remains the same, how to deal with it?

Comment: what is the structure of your json object

Comment: gonna put it in the question

Comment: and the question isn't clear

Comment: im trying to make a Model population but need to populate multiple times the same path